# Get summation value from controller to view

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, sum

Here is my controller function

```
function assignPartner($id){

    $data['projects']=$this->admin_model->getProfData($id,'id','project')->result();
    $data['partners']=$this->admin_model->getTableData('partner')->result();
    $data['budge']=$this->db->query('SELECT SUM(amount) FROM budge WHERE project_id="'.$id.'"')->result();
    //print_r($data);exit;
    $this->load->view('projectheader',$data);
    $this->load->view('assignpartner',$data);
    $this->load->view('projectfooter');

}
```

Here is my view page

```
<?php echo  $budge[0]->amount;?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to alias the sum. If you var_dump $budge in your view you will see the actual name  - should be something messed up like:

```
    $budge[0]->SUM(amount).
```

Change SQL to..

```
    SELECT SUM(amount) AS amount FROM budge WHERE project_id=
```